# Can a Linux (Ubuntu 11) server manage a NTFS partition on a seperate drive on a Windows XP/7 network

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking

I'm hoping to set up my backup machine as an Ubuntu server yet preserve it's seperate 500G NTFS drive as the backup target in a small (< 10 machines) Windows peer to peer network that is a mix of workgroup aware (win XP) and homegroup aware (Win7) machines.  The Linux server will also be used as a test bed for web developemt, especially Ruby.  I'm in a steep learning curve with Ubuntu and have yet to get my Windows machines to recognize the Umbuntu machine on the network.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible?  What am I missing or haven't properly configured on the Ubuntu side so that my Win7 machines can even detect the NTFS drive on the Ubuntu server?

Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 0):

When going across a network like this, the machines don't really care what filesystem the remote system is using. You need to install and configure Samba so that the Windows machines can use SMB/CIFS to access the contents of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

For installation of Samba, Open terminal window (Alt+F2 and type: gnome-terminal) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba
```

When installation finished, Now you need to that folder which you want to share or you can make a new folder.

For installation of Samba in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot Enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Note: Then go to Software Center and Search "glade" & "python-glade" and install both of them

Now start the Samba Server Configuration press(Alt+F2 and type gksu system-config-samba). To add a folder which you want to share click on the + button followed by click on the browse button. Now select the folder which want to share on network. Now enter description and check your folder writable or visible settings. Click on the access tab and give access to the user you want, when you finished click on the OK button. Now your folder is added to your Samba Server Configuration.

Now go to the shared folder, Select the folder then right click on the folder and select Sharing Option. Here add a comment and change the permissions for others to create/delete/modification in files/folders and for the guest access rules.

Samba is Sharing service between Ubuntu to other networks (Windows, linux and others).

**Now install NTFS**

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config ntfs-3g
```

then you just do this command to enable ntfs-config by default

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
```

Comment: Almost there.  It was heavy going thorugh the books and man pages with the prospect of editing the smb.conf and fstab files before I could make that NTFS device visible to Windows Explorer, my primary file system browser.  Thanks for the susicnt instructions.  Still can't see the volumes from the Windows machines, however.  Perhaps a reboot.